# Removing rows that has two columns which may contain the same data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given then following data as an example,

```
Letter One | Letter Two    
         A | B
         B | A
         A | C
```

How can I go about only selecting any rows that have the same data, so in this case I would want the output to remove the second row, as the two letters are the same.
So my output is:

```
Letter One | Letter Two
         A | B 
         A | C
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your query so we can help you with it.

Comment: @WEI_DBA edited!

Comment: You want to SELECT, or DELETE?

Comment: @jarlh it is select

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicated data in the same order? like 2 rows with LetterOne = A and LetterTwo = B

Comment: @Joe no, no duplicated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no exact duplicates, you can do:

```
select letterA, letterB
from t
where letterA <= letterB
union all
select letterA, letterB
from t
where letterA > letterB and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.letterA = t.letterB and t2.letterB = t.letterA);
```

If you don't care about the order of the final columns, you can do:

```
select distinct (case when letterA <= letterB then letterA else letterB end) as letterA,
       (case when letterA > letterB then letterA else letterB end) as letterB
from t;
```

Comment: Great, I used your second answer and it worked. Can you explain how it works at all or point me in the direction of a resource?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
         l1.LetterOne , l1.LetterTwo
FROM
         letters l1
LEFT JOIN
         letters l2 ON l1.LetterOne = l2.LetterTwo AND l1.LetterTwo = l2.LetterOne
WHERE
         l2.LetterOne IS NULL OR l1.LetterOne < l2.LetterOne
```

Comment: This works for only selecting rows with dupilicates, but it excludes the A | C row

Comment: this will not include a row containing  D  | A

Answer (score 1):

The UNION will filter out the duplicates.
The lowest values will be returned in the first column:

```
SELECT LetterOne, LetterTwo
FROM <table>
WHERE LetterOne < LetterTwo
UNION 
SELECT LetterTwo, LetterOne
FROM <table>
WHERE LetterTwo<=LetterOne
```